# Replace substrings in PHP with unique key index

Tags: php, replace

I want to parse:

```
My name is [name]Bob[/name] and her name is [name]Mary[/name].
```

into:

```
My name is {{ $name[1] }} and her name is {{ $name[2] }}.
```

and:

```
public function parse($string)
{
    $pattern = '~\[name\](.*?)\[/name\]~s';

    $matches = preg_match_all($pattern, $string);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $matches; $i++)
    {
        $result[] = '{{ $name['. $i .'] }}';
    }

    return implode(' ', $result);
}
```

returns:

```
{{ $name[1] }} {{ $name[2] }}
```

Question: How do I add this to my string to get the desired result?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) it is:

```
function parse($string)
{
    $pattern = '~\[name\](.*?)\[/name\]~s';
    $i = 1;

    return preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern, 
        function ($m) use (&$i) {
            return '{{ $name['. $i++ .'] }}';
        },
        $string, 
    );
}

echo parse('My name is [name]Bob[/name] and her name is [name]Mary[/name].');
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/gHciO).

Comment: Works! Found a different solution (https://3v4l.org/rNsOO) but I think I'll stick with yours.